# Convert the hexadecimal string representation of some bytes into a byte array in Java

Tags: java

I am having a hard time trying to convert a String containing the hexadecimal representation of some bytes to its corresponding byte array.

I am getting 32bytes using the following code:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
for (int i = 0; i < mdbytes.length; i++) {
    sb.append(Integer.toString((mdbytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
}
return sb.toString();
```

Any idea how to get from the String to the array? In other words, how to do the reverse of the code above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd try commons-codec `byte[] originalBytes = Hex.decodeHex(string.toCharArray())`. In fact I would use it also for the encoding part.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Integer.parseInt(String s, int radix)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method to convert the hexadecimal representation back to an integer, which you can then cast into a byte. Use that to process the string two characters at a time.

Answer (score -1):

Use the

```
String.getBytes();
```

method

Comment: this will give byte array conversion of the already byte representation of the String which will be very different from the original intended Hex.