# Convert array of strings to array of bytes

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a String array, each array element is a *hex* string that consist of 2 chars.

For example the array could be:

```
String a = {"aa","ff","00",.....}
```

How can I convert this array of *strings* to an array of *bytes* in Java?

Comment: I think that your best bet is to create a byte array of the same size as the String array, use a for loop, and inside the loop call `myBytes[i] = Byte.parseByte(myStrings[i], 16)` to parse each String item into a byte (**Edit:** oops, forgot the radix!).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425830/convert-the-hexadecimal-string-representation-of-some-bytes-into-a-byte-array-in use this link, its nearly the same question

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - you should have posted that as an answer.

Comment: @ziesemer: I suppose so. I've got enough rep though.

Comment: it gives an exception when the string is ff !!

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "ff"

Comment: @user1077980: You'll need to check on the range for bytes: the max hex is 7f. You may want to parse to int instead.

Comment: @user1077980. Loop through the array, and convert each STring to a byte using byte b = (byte) (Integer.parseInt(theHexaString, 16) & 0xFF); Byte.parseByte() parses signed bytes only.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to parse unsigned byte hex-strings, use

```
byte[] b = new byte[a.length()];

for (int i=0; i<a.length(); i++) {
    b[i] = (byte) Short.parseShort(a[i], 16);
}
```

"ff" will be parsed to -1, as per [two's compliment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

If you want "ff" to parse to 255 (higher than a java byte can hold) you will need to use shorts

```
short[] b = new short[a.length()];

for (int i=0; i<a.length(); i++) {
    b[i] = Short.parseShort(a[i], 16);
}
```

Comment: Yep, this is what I'm talkin' about. 1+

Comment: yes, but is gives an exception when the string is ff 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "ff"

Comment: @user1077980: The error is yours, not Aaron's. Your error is trying to parse ff. byte's max is 7f. Try parsing to int instead. **Edit:** or use JB Nizet's excellent recommendation!

Comment: Byte.parseByte() only accepts values between -127 and 128. It expects a minus sign for negative numbers and doesnt consider the sign bit as a sign bit. See my comment to your question.

Comment: @Hovercraft: I'm the downvoter. The question makes it clear that "aa" and "ff" must be parse as bytes. Byte.parseByte is not a good suggestion.

Comment: @JBNizet: got it. I thought it was the OP who down-voted the answer. Your suggestion to the original question is good, but I hope the OP isn't expecting a positive number. Methinks he wants to use ints if he's desiring unsigned bytes up to 0xff.

Comment: @JBNizet: Also, I don't even think that your answer requires the `& 0xff` part as the cast should lop off the higher bits.

Comment: To me, a byte is generally not used as a signed number, but as a piece of purely binary data. I find that Java shouldn't have made byte a signed number, because it makes everything more complicated.

Comment: You're right on the & 0xFF. It's needed if he wants to convert the byte to an unsigned int.

Comment: Cheers for the help everyone :)

Answer (score 3):

Loop through the array, and convert each String to a byte using

```
byte b = (byte) (Integer.parseInt(theHexaString, 16));
```

`Byte.parseByte()` parses signed bytes only, and doesn't consider the sign bit as a sign bit.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need the byte representation of the concatenated strings? Something like:

```
public byte[] getBytes(String[] array) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(String s: array) {
       builder.append(s);
    }
    return builder.toString().getBytes();
}
```

Comment: Again, not the parsed bytes. `getBytes()` does not parse the individual Strings into their byte representation but rather uses the default charset encoding of each char -- two very different things. You'll want to delete this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html).

You can then iterate through each string you have and use the [Byte.parseByte()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#parseByte%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method. You can than add it to the ByteArrayOutputStream by using the [write](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#write%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) method.

Once you will have converted all the Strings, you can use the ByteArrayOutputStream's [toByteArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#toByteArray%28%29) method.

Comment: ByteArrayOutputStream would work, but is a little bit overkill here. Also Byte.parseByte() will choke on "ff"